# Disable location sharing's notifications in Microsoft Family Safe

Tags: notifications

I am a parent and I *don't want to* share my location. Is there any way to get rid of this damn nag:

[image]

Or am I forced to see it each time I open up the app.

Also I don't understand why am I seeing following notification each time I unlock my phone:

[image]

if I am NOT sharing my location.

I am running Motorola One (XT1941) with Android 10.